# nginx is ignoring upstream

Tags: nginx, centos, configuration

I'm running nginx on centos 7, and `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` includes a directive to include all configuration files from `conf.d`.

I have a single `myapp.conf` file there with an upstream listening on a domain socket (a Puma server, if that's relevant). However, nginx simply ignores it. There are no errors such as `can't connect to upstream`. Instead nginx tries to serve files from its default location: `/usr/share/niginx/html`.

<del>So, I'd like to see the the final `nginx.conf` after all files were included, to verify that `myapp.conf` is indeed included</del> (see update).

`nginx -t` doesn't show any problem.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/centos/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/centos/apps/myapp/shared/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    disable_symlinks off;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I've introduced a syntax error in`myapp.conf`, and restarted nginx, which failed to start, complaining about the syntax error. Phew, so I guess it is being included. My main problem is still unsolved though.

Output of `nginx -T`, thanks to @Navem:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    disable_symlinks off;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp_nginx.conf:
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/centos/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/centos/apps/myapp/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: The upstream is inside the app.conf or outside, in his own file?

Comment: Inside app.conf

Comment: In nginx.conf, the last lines where si the "include" setion, try to see if nginx do read files from sites-available with *.conf extenstion. Also, you have restared nginx right?

Comment: Yes. I have restarted. How can I see if it does include them? I have `conf.d` instead of `sites-available` since it's centos.

Comment: Post a copy of nginx.con please

Comment: You can also run `nginx -t` to test your configuration for any errors.

Comment: Thanks, added. @MichaelHampton `nginx -t` doesn't report any problem.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the mystery by deleting the `server` context from `nginx.conf`. It comes after the `include` directive, and I guess it overshadowed the `server` and `upstream` blocks from `myapp.conf`, although in the output of `nginx -T`, the latter appears last.

Comment: Good to see you solved it. Suggest you mark this as your answer, so people don't have read the question to try to help.

Answer (score 2):

nginx -T will perform syntax check and dump your final configuration file to stdout.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html

`-T — same as -t, but additionally dump configuration files to standard output (1.9.2).`

Also you could check error log /var/log/nginx/error.log for some runtime errors(can't bind to address for example).

Comment: Thanks, as I've written in the update, I've already verified my conf file is included, but I'll keep it in mind.